# python windows 10 контекстное меню

Tags: python, cmd, windows-10, bat, реестр

Хочу добавить скрипт python (или bat-файл) в контекстное меню windows. В скрипт нужно передать выбранные в папке файлы *(с помощью мыши и зажатой кнопкой ctrl)*.

У меня получилось создать в реестре команду `\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\vertical\command`.

Там есть строковый параметр по умолчанию - `cmd /k D:\SKRIPTS\test.bat`. В КМ появилась команда vertical и она запускает нужный bat и прописанный в нем скрипт.

Вопрос. Как мне передать выбранные файлы в скрипт?

Я хочу выбрать несколько файлов с помощью мыши запустить в КМ команду vertical.

Как все выбранные файлы передать в bat и соответственно в скрипт?

Comment: Если бы напрямую запускался скрипт питона от контекстной команды, я бы посоветовал посмотреть файлы в аргументах `sys.argv` :) Попробуйте в батнике вывести аргументы или передать их в питоничий скрипт, а там уже смотреть в `sys.argv`

Comment: Посмотрите https://stackoverflow.com/q/27088510/1891712

Comment: Попробовал изменить команду на такую - cmd /k C:\Python37-32\python.exe D:\SKRIPTS\test.py. Тоже работает и результат как и прежде - sys.argv: ['D:\\SKRIPTS\\test.py']

Comment: Воспользовался промежуточным вариантом, как передать аргументы в скрипт. BAT примерно такой - python D:\SKRIPTS\test.py %*.  Тогда можно выделив файлы перетащить их на батник. В скрипте они будут в списке sys.argv. Это конечно не контекстное меню, но работает.

Comment: Есть еще не плохой вариант - все-таки сделать КМ, но внести BAT в подменю ОТПРАВИТЬ. Сам батник записать сюда - C:\Users\<имя>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo. А реестр вообще можно не редактировать.

Answer (score 0):

Вот тут посмотри готовый ответ [Перейти](https://xakmika.ru/threads/dobavit-skript-python-ili-fajl-bat-v-kontekstnoe-menju-windows.148/)

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)